# How to delete particular index value form core data,i stored all data according to index

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using this method for deleting coredata according to id but this array returing nil all time.i get all data in fetchRequest but resultss coming nil; Please help me.

```
NSArray* resultss = [appDelegate1.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

 // Here is my code
AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
   NSEntityDescription *path=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Add_Article" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate1.managedObjectContext];
  NSPredicate *deleteParti = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alternate_id == %@",str_articleid];
    [fetchAllData setPredicate:deleteParti];
NSArray* resultss = [appDelegate1.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 NSArray *getAlldata = [delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchAllData error:&error];

    if([getAlldata count] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"no found data");
    }
    else
    {
        for(NSManagedObject *objectName in getAlldata)
        {
            [delegate.managedObjectContext deleteObject:objectName];
        }
        NSError *error;
        [delegate.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    }
```

it'not working. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];



NSEntityDescription *path=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Add_Article" inManagedObjectContext:context];



NSPredicate *deleteParti = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alternate_id == %@",str_articleid];

// I am assuming that fetchAllData is your current NSFetchRequest object
[fetchAllData setEntity:path];
[fetchAllData setPredicate:deleteParti];



NSArray *getAlldata = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchAllData error:&error];

if([getAlldata count] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"no found data");
}
else
{
    for(NSManagedObject *objectName in getAlldata)
    {
        [context deleteObject:objectName];
    }
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
}
```

Please change your code to this. It should work now. 
Best of luck

Comment: Hello Sir, i put this code but this time also NSArray *getAlldata showing nil.

Comment: Hello Sir,Thanks it is working before which code i used in that i was sending   wrong parameter,

Comment: Yeah.. Sometime it happens